# Unable to receive response from rest api in spring on front end

Tags: java, html, json

i am attempting to return a response result from spring in java to a html page but failing to receive the response. Basically my searchRoom method attempts to search a room for availability and if it's available returns true or else false. My response message is passed to the html file and upon the response should inform the user if available or not. But i am not able to receive the response please could someone tell me what i did wrong. And a side note i tried to do a console log but failed to print either true or false.

Below is my Java Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guest/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String SearchRoom(@RequestBody Occupancy occupancy, ModelMap model){

        boolean result = occupancyservice.searchAvlRoom(occupancy);
        System.out.print(result);
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        return "guest";
    }
```

Below is my query function that post the data and receives response:

```
 $("#checkAvailabilityForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData={
            "checkInDate": $("#checkInDate").val(),
            "checkOutDate": $("#checkOutDate").val(),
            "roomsWanted":$("#roomsWanted").val(),
            "room":{
                "roomType": $("input[name=roomType]:checked").val(),
                "roomProperties":$("input[name=roomProperties]:checked").val()
            }

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'guest/search',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(dataRecieved){
                var dataRecieved= $.trim(dataRecieved);
                console.log(dataRecieved);
                /*if(dataRecieved === ''){

                }else{

                }*/
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured it out. I forgot to use @ResponseBody annotation and the code below solved my problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guest/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean SearchRoom(@RequestBody Occupancy occupancy){
        boolean result = occupancyservice.searchAvlRoom(occupancy);
        return result;
    }
```